# Terminology for `non-inversion'

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, terminology

An inversion in a sequence is a pair of elements that are out of their natural order. Let $\pi $  be a permutation. There is an inversion of $\pi $  between $i$ and $j$ if $i<j$ and $\pi (i)>\pi (j)$.

I am just curious that how people call the pair which is not an inversion. Are there any names for it (i.e., (i,j) with $i<j$ and $\pi (i)<\pi (j)$)?

Comment: I don’t know, but if I were really pressed for a name, I would simply say “$\pi$ preserves the ordering of $(i,j)$”.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thx! I did quite some search but failed to find a name for it.

Comment: If you don't find a name, you could ask yourself how is this number relevant? I honestly never had to use it. If it's not that relevant why wasting a name on it?